# Identifying when fixed effects have changed in a GLMM

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, inference, glmm

I have a dataset spanning several years, that I have analysed year by year (using the same glmm model code) to determine whether the random effect (random intercept) has altered over time. I have found that it has altered.

Now I am concerned that the fixed effects have also altered, which may mean that I can't compare the random effects year by year. To determine this, I have obtained confidence intervals for all the fixed effects for each year and compared the intervals. My thinking is that if the confidence intervals for a fixed effect for each year all overlap then that fixed effect can be assumed to be the same - is this faulty reasoning ? Is there a better way ? If this is a reasonable approach then does it imply that if the confidence intervals do not overlap then the fixed effect *has* changed ?

Comment: Re: "My thinking is that if the confidence intervals for a fixed effect for each year all overlap then that fixed effect can be assumed to be the same" this is a little bit too strong of a statement - you just _don't have strong evidence that they do change_. I think you're on the right track though - you can do a test of whether stratifying by time provides a meaningful increase in the fit of the model (using, for example, the likelihood ratio test)

Comment: @Macro , thank you (again). _"don't have strong evidence that they do change"_....so would that be the same as not rejecting the null hypothesis that they are the same ?

Comment: I don't think the likelihood ratio test will necessarily give you the same results as checking the confidence intervals for overlap. The ladder is more akin to pairwise testing whereas the likelihood ratio test is more along the lines of an "omnibus test"

Comment: Yes that's right. Not rejecting the null hypothesis doesn't mean that the null hypothesis is true, which is why I said your conclusion may be too strong.

Comment: Macro has actually answered the question.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I think there may be a bit more to it though. For example, when you stratify by year, should you also let the random effect variances change from year to year? In that case you're fitting an entirely different model for each year. Or, should you just include interactions with the year dummy variables, effectively just allowing the fixed effects to vary by year while leaving the random effect variances fixed? My guess is the former would be most appropriate but then it's not clear what the right degrees of freedom for the $\chi^2$ statistic is.

Comment: @Macro the point of stratifying by year was to observe whether the random effect $has$ changed from year to year. I don't think I would be able to do that if I use the full dataset and have dummy variables for each year ?

Comment: You could include random slopes in the dummy variables, Joe

Comment: @Macro I like the sound of that, but now sure how to implement it. ATM I have `glmer( bull~p1+p2+p3+p4+p5+(1|school),subset=(yr=2011),data=bull, family=binomial(link=logit))`. If the indicator variables were i1, i2, i3, ... , i6 , how would I code that ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how `glmer()` is different from `lmer()`, but in `lmer` you would do: `lmer( bull~p1+p2+p3+p4+p5+(i1+i2+i3+i4+i5+i6-1|school),data=bull, family=binomial(link=logit))` where you've deleted the random intercept since it isn't identified from the first dummy variable.

Comment: @Macro OK got it. That works, but I am not sure how to interpret the output in terms of the REs changing year by year. I know this is going off topic now, so I wonder if it would be acceptable for me to write a new question on this, that you could answer ?

Comment: Joe, it estimates changes in the random effect _variance_ over time (and therefore a change in the intraclass correlations over time). If you post a new question, I'm not sure I can answer, but I can try :)